# Cómo mostrar porcentajes en gráfica de pastel con Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Estoy en el desarrollo de unas gráficas con la ayuda de la biblioteca de funciones Chart.js y entre ellas estoy haciendo uso de un gráfico de pastel, o también conocido con *pie chart*.

Estoy buscando alguna manera de agregar sus respectivos porcentajes sobre la gráfica, así como la imagen que agrego de ejemplo al final del fragmento de código.

Actualmente se muestra la gráfica, pero no logro mostrar sus respectivos porcentajes.

A continuación muestro el código que estoy usando:

```js
const pieData = [
    {
        value: 72,
        color: "#4EADEB",
       // highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Avance"
    },
    {
        value: 28,
        color: "#3F86CB",
        //highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Pendiente"
    }
];

const pieOptions = {
    //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
    segmentShowStroke: true,   

    //String - The colour of each segment stroke
    segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",

    //Number - The width of each segment stroke
    segmentStrokeWidth: 2,

    //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
    percentageInnerCutout: 0, // This is 0 for Pie charts

    //Number - Amount of animation steps
    animationSteps: 100,

    //String - Animation easing effect
    animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",

    //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
    animateRotate: true,

    //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
    animateScale: false,

    //String - A legend template
    legendTemplate:
        '<ul class="<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>'
};

const pieCtx = document.getElementById("myPieGraph").getContext("2d");
const myPieChart = new Chart(pieCtx).Pie(pieData, pieOptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.1.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.1.1/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myPieGraph" height="120" width="240"></canvas>
```

**Resultado esperado:**

[image: Resultado esperado]

Comment: puede hacerlo accediendo a `options.tooltips.callbacks.label: function(` en las versiones nuevas, aunque estas utilizando la version 1.1.1 cuando van por la version 3.5.0...

Comment: @Bryro Ya me perdí, desde donde puedo acceder al apartado que mencionas ? adicional estoy buscando hacerlo para esta versión ya que cuento con mas de 60 graficas sobre esta librería e implicaría mucho tiempo migrar a las versiones mas recientes de ChartJS

Comment: @Bryro , ese tipo de elementos aparecen solo al pasar el ratón sobre el área de la tarta, no se queda permanentemente dibujado en ella.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chart.js no soporta introducir texto dentro de un gráfico de tarta en ninguna de sus versiones, pero existe un complemento que permite hacerlo:

- [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/)

Si decides subir la versión de Chart.js a 3.5.0, entonces un ejemplo de uso sería el siguiente:

```js
const pieData = {
  labels: [
    "Avance",
    "Pendiente",
  ],
  datasets: [{
    data: [ 72, 28 ],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#4EADEB",
      "#3F86CB",
    ],
    hoverOffset: 4,
  }],
};

var pieCtx = myPieGraph.getContext('2d');

var myPieChart = new Chart(pieCtx, {
  /* IMPORTANTE: cargamos el complemento */
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  type: 'pie',
  data: pieData,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        /* anchor puede ser "start", "center" o "end" */
        anchor: "center",
        /* Podemos modificar el texto a mostrar */
        formatter: (dato) => dato + "%",
        /* Color del texto */
        color: "black",
        /* Formato de la fuente */
        font: {
          family: '"Times New Roman", Times, serif',
          size: "28",
          weight: "bold",
        },
        /* Formato de la caja contenedora */
        //padding: "4",
        //borderWidth: 2,
        //borderColor: "darkblue",
        //borderRadius: 8,
        //backgroundColor: "lightblue"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-asxKqQghC1oBShyhiBwA+YgotaSYKxGP1rcSYTDrB0U6DxwlJjU59B67U8+5/++uFjcuVM8Hh5cokLjZlhm3Vg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-R/QOHLpV1Ggq22vfDAWYOaMd5RopHrJNMxi8/lJu8Oihwi4Ho4BRFeiMiCefn9rasajKjnx9/fTQ/xkWnkDACg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<canvas id="myPieGraph" style="max-height: 200px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta clara y concisa.